# How To: Atomic Swaps

Tags: exchange, p2p-exchange

How do you trustlessly exchange BTC for XMR?

Answer (score 3):

Originally posted on the Monero subreddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/qb7t8p/how_to_atomic_swaps/, u/dEBRUYNE_1 requested I post it here too. Please excuse the mis-tagging; I apparently lack the reputation to create appropriate tags.

I flatter myself that I'm at least an above-average user of Google, a relatively competent computer user, and have an acceptable level of understanding of the mechanics of blockchains and cryptocurrencies in general, and yet I frankly found the comit atomic swap tool to be a pain in the ass to figure out. A couple of days of experiments, Googling around, and reading the Github issues page later, I feel a lot more comfortable with it. I am not part of the Comit team, just a dude who was frustrated looking for answers on Google.

This post is for people like me - people who kinda-sorta-maybe generally know what they're doing but are approaching atomic swaps for the first time - to have all the information I've gleaned in one place in a handy step-by-step guide. I am not an expert on the subject and if there are any inaccuracies in this post I'd love to be corrected by people who know more than I do.

So, without further ado:

### **How to swap BTC for XMR using swap (or swap.exe if you're thatway inclined)**

- **Before you begin: This can be a long-ish process (you'll be waiting
  around for a total of 20 XMR and 4 BTC confirmations before
  everything's done) and for the best chance of a smooth ride, you need
  to maintain a connection to the provider throughout. Plan accordingly
  if your connectivity isn't reliable. There are ways to remedy an
  interrupted swap, but not in all circumstances - the issues page of
  the Github contains a couple of questions where XMR or BTC was
  apparently unrecoverable. Proceed with caution.**
- The easiest place to start your journey is
  https://unstoppableswap.net/ which will provide you with a list of
  swap providers. Some caveats with this:

  - Be aware that some are on testnet, while some are on mainnet. Be sure
    to look at the tags.
  - Also be aware that a provider's presence on the list is not an
    indicator of anything other than the provider being online. It does
    not guarantee that they have sufficient XMR to make swaps for the
    amount of BTC they claim as their maximum (or indeed for any amount),
    nor that their swap provider server is actually functioning
    correctly. More on that lower down. Choose your provider carefully.
  - It is possible to bypass unstoppableswap and get a list of providers
    from the swap binary if you specify a rendezvous point. I don't know
    enough about this to talk about it here, so I won't.
- Choose your provider and fill in the amount of BTC you want to swap.
  Click Swap and fill in the form. Follow through the instructions to
  download swap (for *NIX) or [download it manually (easier for Windows
  users)](https://github.com/comit-network/xmr-btc-swap/releases/latest) and then copy the command it handily generates for you.
- The command will be something like:

  ```
  ./swap buy-xmr --receive-address $YOUR_MONERO_ADDRESS --seller $YOUR_CHOSEN_SELLER --change-address $BTC_ADDRESS_YOU_CONTROL
  ```
- Run it. If your provider is reachable, you will see output like the
  following. If your provider is not reachable, start again from the
  top and pick another.

  ```
  Connected to Alice at $YOUR_CHOSEN_SELLER
   Received quote price=$PRICE BTC minimum_amount=$BTC_MIN BTC maximum_amount=$BTC_MAX BTC
   [QR CODE]
   Waiting for Bitcoin deposit deposit_address=$BTC_ADDRESS max_giveable=$BTC_SPENDABLE_THISWALLET BTC minimum_amount=$BTC_MIN BTC maximum_amount=$BTC_MAX BTC
  ```
- Confirm that you are happy to swap at the exchange rate given by
  $PRICE. Also now would be a good time to check on BTC transaction
  fees to make sure you aren't about to spend thousands of sats on a
  transfer.
- If you're unhappy with tx fees, you can afford to wait a bit. There
  doesn't appear to be a timeout on the swap at this stage.
- Presuming that everything is okay, you should now transfer an amount
  of BTC between ($BTC_MIN+$TX_FEE) and $BTC_MAX to the address
  indicated by $BTC_ADDRESS. **You must account for the onward BTC
  transaction fees here**, otherwise the amount that $BTC_ADDRESS can
  spend could be lower than $BTC_MIN. I will admit with some
  embarrassment that I didn't think of that at all the first time I
  tried a swap, so I ended up having to make two transfers into
  $BTC_ADDRESS, and pay two lots of transaction fees.
- This amount does not have to be the amount you told unstoppableswap
  you were going to swap. As far as I can tell, unstoppableswap only
  asks how much you want to swap so it can validate your choice of
  provider.
- When your BTC transfer is broadcast (interestingly, it doesn't appear
  in my experience to require confirmation, merely broadcast and
  acceptance into the BTC mempool), you will see output like this:

  ```
  Received Bitcoin new_balance=$XFER_AMOUNT BTC max_giveable=$BTC_SPENDABLE_THISWALLET
   Determined swap amount amount=$BTC_SPENDABLE_THISWALLET BTC fees=$FEE BTC
   Starting new swap swap_id=$SWAPID
  ```
- Several of my swap attempts have gone wrong at this point, usually
  before the assignment of a $SWAPID. Some failed with cryptic error
  messages (see below for a table) and some with a message that the swap provider does
  not have sufficient XMR to fulfil the swap request.
- If your swap errors out and drops you back at the terminal/command
  prompt here, **DO    NOT PANIC**. You can initiate a transfer of your
  BTC with the command    below. This will work to withdraw the BTC
  back where it came from, or    you could use it to transfer to the
  new $BTC_ADDRESS when you retry    the swap.

  ```
  ./swap withdraw-btc --address $DEST_BTC_ADDRESS
  ```
- Assuming nothing has failed and swap is still running, however,
  you'll see output like this:

  ```
  Published Bitcoin transaction txid=$ONWARD_TXID kind=lock
   Waiting for Alice to lock Monero
  ```
- Alice is waiting for two block confirmations for $ONWARD_TXID. From
  this point, you are no longer able to use the

  ```
  withdraw-btc
  ```

  command to
  halt the swap. While you and Alice wait for the two block
  confirmations, go get a coffee or eat some soup or something. The
  terminal will not update until there are two block confirmations. I
  don't know about you, but I find it unnerving to stare at an
  unchanging terminal when I know for a fact there should be a process
  going on, so I prefer to just not look at it for a while.
- Once $ONWARD_TXID has the two block confirmations you should receive
  a message confirming that Alice has locked the XMR you're going to
  receive, and an XMR txid. swap will keep reporting the number of
  confirmations until the required 10 are received. **THIS IS NOT THE
  FINAL TRANSFER TO YOUR XMR WALLET. This is the lock transaction where
  Alice transfers XMR from an internal wallet to the multisig lock
  wallet.**

  - If you lose connection to Alice during this time, the swap will be
    halted, but can be resumed, and depending on exact circumstances it
    will either complete the transfer of XMR to your wallet or refund
    your BTC to the $BTC_ADDRESS_YOU_CONTROL you specified at the top. To
    resume a halted swap, you must use

    ```
    swap resume --swap-id $SWAPID
    ```

    If you don't have the $SWAPID, you can check it with

    ```
    swap history
    ```

    which will give you the state and ID of every swap you've started. Of
    course the state database is persistent, so even if you had a power
    failure, you can resume.
- Now that Alice's XMR lock transaction is confirmed, swap will proceed
  with transferring both the BTC and XMR to their final destinations.
  Two transactions (one XMR, one BTC) are broadcast, but swap will only
  tell you the txid for your XMR transfer to your wallet on the
  terminal, and then exit.
- Congratulations, when you have 10 confirmations for the txid that
  swap gave you, you will have successfully received XMR in exchange
  for BTC, in a completely trustless fashion.

### **Stuff that has gone wrong for me, with solutions:**

| Error | Cause/Solution |
| --- | --- |
| ``` Error: Failed to complete swap Caused by: 0: Failed to deserialize bytes into message using CBOR 1: EOF while parsing a value ``` | No idea why this happens. Find a new swap provider, try again. Use ``` swap withdraw-btc --address=<$DEST_BTC_ADDRESS> ``` to reclaim BTC. |
| ``` Error: Failed to complete swap Caused by: Seller's XMR balance is currently too low to fulfill the swap request to buy $SWAP_AMOUNT BTC, please try again later ``` | Wait for swap provider to replenish their XMR wallet (many seem to do this manually for the moment) or try a different provider. Use ``` swap withdraw-btc --address=<$DEST_BTC_ADDRESS> ``` to reclaim BTC. |
| ``` monero-wallet-rpc failed to fetch transaction, may need to be restarted txid=$XMR_TXID ``` | Not necessarily fatal. May indicate a loss of connection. If swap exits to terminal without reporting ``` Successfully transferred XMR to wallet monero_receive_address=$XMR_ADDRESS ``` then use ``` swap resume --swap-id=<$SWAPID> ``` to complete the swap. Use ``` swap history ``` to determine $SWAPID if unknown. Swap can be resumed hours or days later, but may 'complete' by refunding BTC rather than transferring XMR. |
| ``` Lost connection to Alice at $YOUR_CHOSEN_SELLER, cause: Connection error: I/O error: connection is closed ``` | Fatal. Definitely lost connection. Use ``` swap resume --swap-id=<$SWAPID> ``` to complete the swap. Use ``` swap history ``` to determine $SWAPID if unknown. Swap can be resumed hours or days later, but may complete by refunding BTC rather than transferring XMR. |

In all cases, the state db can be queried with

```
swap history
```

and will give you clues on where the XMR and BTC are (internal wallet; lock (multisig) wallet - confirmed or unconfirmed; successfully redeemed). Also, the tool maintains detailed logs to help with further diagnosis at C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\xmr-btc-swap\data\cli\mainnet\logs on Windows and I believe in ~/.xmr-btc-swap/data/cli/mainnet/logs for *NIX.

I hope this post is useful to someone, and I welcome corrections or expansion, as this is based on two days of me failing in a variety of entertaining (but apparently not uncommon) ways to complete swaps. YMMV, stay safe.